# Custom Macro for Sum Symbol

Tags: macros

I want to write a macro which makes a transformation for the sum symbol.

When i write:

```
\csum_{i = 1000000}^{n}
```

it should be converted to this:

```
\sum_{\mathclap{i = 1000000}}^{n} \;
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Why `\mathclap`?

Comment: because it looks much better if you have a long subscript

Comment: I've been wondering for a while it there would be an easy & automated system to do this with `xparse`, some sort of auto implementing `t_ g t^ g` automatically. With an interface so that actually the sup- and subscript are treated like optional arguments, hence easier to change the behaviour of them.

Comment: How about an interface like `\csum{_{<sub>}^{sup}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this???

I am not fond of the `_^` syntax of `\sum` at all, so I dropped this.

The optional argument to `\csum` is set to the counting index `i` if omitted.

I kept the `\mathclap`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\NewDocumentCommand{\csum}{+O{i}+m+m}{%
\ensuremath{\sum\limits_{\mathclap{#1=#2}}^{#3}}%
}%


\begin{document}
\[ \csum{100000}{m} = 17 \]

\[ \csum[k]{100000}{m} = 17 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit -- Version with optional 3rd argument instead of mandatory**

The great benefit from `xparse` and its macros like `\NewDocumentCommand` is the better argument handling compared to `\newcommand`. It's quite easy to define the superscript argument to be optional:

`\csum[summation variable]{start value}[upper limit]`

Since `\sum\limits_{}` etc. works without `^{}` a default optional empty argument value is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\csum}{+O{i}+m+O{}}{%
\ensuremath{\sum\limits_{\mathclap{#1=#2}}^{#3}}%
}%


\begin{document}
\[ \csum{100000}[m] = 17 \]

\[ \csum[k]{1}[N] = \dfrac{N \left({N+1}\right)}{2} \]

\[ \csum[k]{1} k = 5050 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think this is a more robust approach. How can i change this that \csum{}{} and \csum{} works depending if i want a superscript or not?

Comment: @user3613886: See my update please

Answer (score 3):

### Edit

In case you are *definitely* going to have sub- and superscript after *every* `\csum`, *always*… in that case it's easier, I think:

```
\def\csum_#1^#2{\sum_{\mathclap{#1}}^{#2}}
```

But you *always* have to input it with both of them.

In case you want to be able to say, sometimes `\csum x_i`, here's a very fragile approach.

### Original

Very fragile, but a first approach

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\csum{t_ g t^ g}
 {\sum
  \IfBooleanT{#1}
    {_{\mathclap{#2}}}
  \IfBooleanT{#3}
    {^{#4}}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\;}{\IfBooleanT{#3}{\;}}}

\begin{document}
First, what we want,
\[
  \sum_{i = 1000000}^{n} x_i \quad \text{should change to} \quad \sum_{\mathclap{i = 1000000}}^{n} \; x_i
\]
And here we try with our new fragile-defined-easily-breakable command
\[
  \csum_{i = 1000000}^{n} x_i \qquad \text{Hurray!}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, limitations: you can't have a brace following `\sum` directly (like `\sum {x_n}`; the sub-superscripts must be braced in case of been given (e.g., this wouldn't work: `\sum_{i=1}^n` you have to `\sum_{i=1}^{n}`.

It would be nice that in the future, an expl3 package that provides math macros would also give a more “robust” way of configuring sub and subscripts. It's easy to define such macros with optional arguments, but it's still nice to have `\sum_i^\infty` with `_` and `^` tokens. So we could, with an interface, prepend code to subscripts, or may be add a predefined kern to such superscript, etc.

Comment: yes it would be great if _ and ^ would work always, thank you anyway.

Comment: They work always. The think is, in the first option, in case you *don't want* a superscript, you still need to write `^{}`, e.g., if you want `\csum_{i} x_i` you still need `\csum_{i}^{}` (but thinking about it, in that case you would be better using `\sum` directly).